# How can i change the order of strings on a line based on a pattern?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have files with data, but some lines have the data in the wrong order:

```
name cat
value 7.25 label X
value 1.13 label 2
value 15.75 label 1  
name dog
label 1 value 20.00
label X value 9.00
label 2 value 1.10  
name cow
value 1.10 label 2
value 8.25 label X
value 19.00 label 1  
name sheep
value 1.11 label 2
value 8.80 label X
value 19.00 label 1  
name mouse
value 1.13 label 2
value 8.00 label X
value 19.00 label 1  
name donkey
value 1.05 label 2
value 9.50 label X
value 16.00 label 1  
name dog
label 1 value 20.00
label X value 9.00
label 2 value 1.10
```

As you can see some lines start with label * , and some lines start with value * , 
I wish to swap the order of the strings when the line begins with 'value' so all lines (ignoring the line containing name) are in this format `'Label * value *'`

Desired Output:

```
name cat
label X value 7.25
label 2 value 1.13
label 1 value 15.75  
name dog
label 1 value 20.00
label X value 9.00
label 2 value 1.10  
name cow
label 2 value 1.10
label X value 8.25
label 1 value 19.00 
name sheep
label 2 value 1.11
label X value 8.80
label 1 value 19.00  
name mouse
label 2 value 1.13
label X value 8.00
label 1 value 19.00  
name donkey
label 2 value 1.05
label X value 9.50
label 1 value 16.00  
name dog
label 1 value 20.00
label X value 9.00
label 2 value 1.10
```

I have tried writing a loop, grepping for lines that start with 'value' , however i am not sure on the next steps.

How can i acheive this?

Comment: You seem to be doing a fair bit of text file manipulation lately so please make sure to read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and be aware that the guys who invented shell also invented awk for shell to call when general text manipulation is necessary. With that in mind and seeing your answers here you'll understand why `writing a loop, grepping for lines that start with 'value'` would never be the right starting point just to manipulate text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This job is pretty much a perfect fit for `awk`:

```
awk '$1 == "value" { print $3, $4, $1, $2; next; } 1'
```

`awk` programs consist of condition/operation pairs; the code inside the first block is run only if `$1 == "value"` is true, reversing the operations in that case; the `1` is a bare condition (which thus gets a default operation of printing the whole line, which runs whenever the first condition was not run (with its `next` command causing flow control to skip directly to the next line of input).

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
sed 's/^\(label .* \)\(value .*\)/\2 \1/'
```

Comment: This will leave whitespace at the end of the amended lines, perhaps `sed -E 's/^(label .*) *(value.*)/\2 \1/' file`

Answer (score 2):

Charles' answer is good for this problem but something else to consider if you have tag-value pairs in other, more complicated contexts is to first create an array of those pairs and then print them however you like by their tags/names:

```
$ awk '
    function p(tag) { return (tag OFS f[tag]) }
    NF==4 { for (i=1;i<NF;i+=2) f[$i]=$(i+1); $0=p("label") OFS p("value") }
1' file
name cat
label X value 7.25
label 2 value 1.13
label 1 value 15.75
name dog
label 1 value 20.00
label X value 9.00
label 2 value 1.10
name cow
label 2 value 1.10
label X value 8.25
label 1 value 19.00
name sheep
label 2 value 1.11
label X value 8.80
label 1 value 19.00
name mouse
label 2 value 1.13
label X value 8.00
label 1 value 19.00
name donkey
label 2 value 1.05
label X value 9.50
label 1 value 16.00
name dog
label 1 value 20.00
label X value 9.00
label 2 value 1.10
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution need gawk (gnu awk) instead of the traditional awk. Here it is:

```
BEGIN {
        IGNORECASE = 1;
    }
    {
        if( match( $0, \
          /value[[:space:]]+([0-9\.]+)[[:space:]]+label[[:space:]]+([0-9A-Z]+)/,
          groups ) )
          printf( "label %s value %s\n", groups[2], groups[1]);
        else
          print $0;
    }
```